# What does => and () => mean in Scala

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala and I really like it, but sometimes it surprises me. For instance:

```
clickedCallbacks: List[() => Unit])
```

Could anyone tell me what `=>` and `() =>` mean in Scala?

Comment: Please check this Blog post "[How do I find what some symbol means or does?](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-symbols.html)"

Answer (score 151, accepted):

`=>` is syntactic sugar for creating instances of functions. Recall that every function in scala is an instance of a class.

For example, the type `Int => String`, is equivalent to the type `Function1[Int,String]` i.e. a function that takes an argument of type `Int` and returns a `String`.

```
  scala> val f: Function1[Int,String] = myInt => "my int: "+myInt.toString
  f: (Int) => String = <function1>

  scala> f(0)
  res0: String = my int: 0

  scala> val f2: Int => String = myInt => "my int v2: "+myInt.toString
  f2: (Int) => String = <function1>

  scala> f2(1)
  res1: String = my int v2: 1
```

Here `myInt` is bound to the argument value passed to `f` and `f2`.

`() => T` is the type of a function that takes no arguments and returns a `T`. It is equivalent to `Function0[T]`. `()` is called a zero parameter list I believe.

```
 scala> val f: () => Unit = () => { println("x")}
 f: () => Unit = <function0>

 scala> f()
 x

scala> val f2: Function0[Unit] = () => println("x2")
f: () => Unit = <function0>

scala> f2()
x2
```

Comment: In the first line after the first example code you use the word "binded". Is that a jargon word to mean something specific in this context, or would "bound" make sense there?

Answer (score 132):

`=>` has several meanings in Scala, all related to its mathematical meaning as implication.

- In a value, it introduces a function literal, or *lambda*.  e.g. the bit inside the curly braces in `List(1,2,3).map { (x: Int) => x * 2 }`
- In a type, with symbols on both sides of the arrow (e.g. `A => T`, `(A,B) => T`, `(A,B,C) => T`, etc.) it's sugar for `Function<n>[A[,B,...],T]`, that is, a function that takes parameters of type `A[,B...]`, and returns a value of type `T`.

  - Empty parens on the left hand side (e.g. `() => T`) indicate that the function takes no parameters (also sometimes called a "thunk");
  - Empty parens on the right hand side denote that it returns `()`—the sole value of type `Unit`, whose name can also be written `()`—confused yet? :)

    A function that returns Unit is also known as a *procedure*, normally a method that's called only for its side effect.
- In the type declaration for a method or function parameter, with no symbol on the left hand side (e.g. `def f(param: => T)`) it's a "by-name parameter", meaning that is evaluated every time it's used within the body of the function, and not before.  Ordinary "by-value" parameters are evaluated before entry into the function/method.
- In a `case` clause, they separate the pattern (and optional guard) from the result expression, e.g. `case x => y`.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for the "by-name parameter" meaning, not mentioned in any other answer. It is used when "lazy evaluation" is required.

Comment: "  val getNull = (v: Int) => None: Option[String]" here => means call-by-name ?

Comment: @AshikaUmangaUmagiliya in your example it's a lambda... You're creating an anonymous function from `Int => Option[String]` (aka a value of type `Function1[Int, Option[String]]`) and binding it to the name `getNull`. :)

Answer (score 28):

As the most simplified answer, you can substitute whatever is on the left-hand side of => with the word "LEFT" and whatever is on the right-hand side with the word "RIGHT".

Then, the meaning of "**LEFT => RIGHT**" becomes:

**Take LEFT then do RIGHT.**

This means that if you have a "()=>" that you can take nothing (that is, no parameters) and then do whatever is on the right-hand side.

This is the most common meaning.

Answer (score 20):

`() => Unit` means: *"Type function that takes no parameters and return nothing"*

So if you declare a value `f` to be a function that takes no parameters and returns nothing its type would be:

```
val f : () => Unit
```

Since this is a `val` you have to assign a value, for instance a function that prints `Hola mundo`

```
val f : () => Unit  = () => println("Hola Mundo")
```

That reads: *"f is a function that takes no parameters and returns nothing initialized with the code `println("Hola Mundo")`

Since in Scala you can use type inference you don't have to declare the type so the following would be equivalent:

```
val f = () => println("Hola Mundo")
```

To invoke it you can just:

```
f()

>"Hola mundo"
```

Or, since the functions are also objects you can invoke the `apply` method:

```
f.apply()
> "Hola Mundo"
```

That's why in your declaration you're saying *"I'll have a list that will hold functions with no params and no return types"*  hence  List[()=>Unit]

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

`=>` is the "function arrow". It is used both in function type signatures as well as anonymous function terms. `() => Unit` is a shorthand for `Function0[Unit]`, which is the type of functions which take no arguments and return nothing useful (like `void` in other languages).