# scala => operator?

Tags: scala, syntax, operators, pattern-matching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does => and () => mean in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951895/what-does-and-mean-in-scala)

In Scala, what does the => operator do? For example, in the below case statement:

```
myVar match
{
  case 1 => print(num1 + num2)
}
```

Is the "operator" just a shorthand way of writing something more verbose?

Comment: Use [SymbolHound](http://symbolhound.com/) to lookup non-googlable things like _ :: => operators in scala.

Comment: Now I know why they call him om-nom-nom.  Read Alex Cruise's answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6952195/1296806 and then follow the possible dupe to Daniel Sobral's http://stackoverflow.com/a/4545703/1296806.  Not everything is an operator. Sometimes a cigar is just a cigar.