# Scala - Confused with lazy syntax

Tags: scala

Hello I'm reading the book called "Functional Programming in Scala". Book had code like this

```
trait Stream[+A] {
  def uncons: Option[(A, Stream[A])]
  def isEmpty: Boolean = uncons.isEmpty
}
object Stream {
...
def cons[A](hd: => A, tl: => Stream[A]): Stream[A] =
  new Stream[A] {
    lazy val uncons = Some((hd, tl))
  }
...
```

it says that `hd: => A` syntax is making this a lazy val

---

But [the code in the github repo](https://github.com/pchiusano/fpinscala) had something like this

```
trait Stream[+A]{
  def toList: List[A] = {
        @annotation.tailrec
        def go(s: Stream[A], acc: List[A]) : List[A] = s match {
          case Cons(h,t) => go(t(), h() :: acc)
          case _ => acc
        }

        go(this, List()).reverse
      }
    }
case class Cons[+A](h: ()=>A, t: () => Stream[A]) extends Stream[A]
```

1. What is the difference between `h: =>A` and `h: ()=>A`.
2. Why is the second part of code has `()` after argument like `go(t(), h(), :: acc)`

Comment: 1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951895/what-does-and-mean-in-scala 2. By adding braces you distinguish actual function invocation from referencing function object (which can be done via simple `t` or `h`)

Comment: so if I pass `1 : Int` as argument is it gonna become `1()`?

Comment: nope, because `1: Int` is not a function, it's just a value, unlike `()=>A` or `h: ()=>A` which are objects, that represent functions

Comment: So that explains why one constructor was turning values into functions like this `Cons(() => head, () => tail)`. To match the `h: ()=>A` type right?

Comment: Not only to match, but, in general, to evaluate the part on the right of `=>` only after invocation. Such transformation is usually referred as construction of *[thunks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk)*