# What does "type T = .." mean in Scala?

Tags: scala, syntax, types

```
type Set = Int => Boolean
```

I'm trying figure out what this means. From my understanding `type` is like an alias, but I'm not sure how that's different from using `def`. If my teacher wouldn't have told me to use `type`, I would have went with `def`. I also need a little clarity on the what the rest means. So we have a type named `Set`, that is `Int`, but what does `=> Boolean` mean?

Comment: Uh... how would you try to define a type alias using `def`?

Comment: Partially a duplicate of [_What does => and () => mean in Scala_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951895/what-does-and-mean-in-scala).

Comment: im just starting scala , i have no idea what the diff between a type and deff are. sorry lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `type` keyword creates a type alias.  Very similar to `typedef` in C++ if you know that.  The purpose is to assign context-specific names to generic things.  So in a `Person` class you might do `type Firstname = String` / `type Lastname = String` just so you can differentiate the two fields by type and not confuse them (this is a stupid example but it's past midnight so deal with it).

In this case, you're defining `Set` to be an alias of `Int => Boolean`, which is the type of a function that takes `Int` and returns `Boolean`.  I'm not exactly sure why that constitutes a "set", but that's what the code means.

Comment: Presumably that's a "set" because we can view a set as a function taking a potential element and returning true or false depending on whether that element is in the set. (so the set of evens would return i%2==0, for an obvious example)

Answer (score -1):

#### **T** within square brackets `[T]`

I'm completely new to Scala, and when I got to this post I was actually trying to understand what the meaning of **T** within square brackets was `[T]` and, I found that it refers to the *type of the elements in this '[object](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.1/scala/collection/mutable/WrappedArray.html)'* (WrappedArray was the object I was reading about).

[image]

...just in case this helps someone.

Comment: Does not answer the current (5 year old) question because `type T = ...` is very different from `[T]` which is a type parameter that might **or might not** "refer to the type of the elements in this object".

Comment: That's why I've added the (0 year old) comment: *"when I got to this post I was actually trying to understand what the meaning of T within square brackets was"* to clarify my post **with** a **screenshot** of what I've read and where I've read it. It is a common way of sharing related information **without** opening a brand new question for it... that's all.