# What does ()=> mean in Scala?

Tags: scala

I understand that a "call by name" argument is defined as `foo(arg: => T)` but, what does this mean?

```
def foo(block: => T) = {
  List(1, 2, 3).map(_ => ()=>block)
}
```

Specially I don't understant the `()=>` part.

Wouldn't it be enough to write `map(_ => argByName)` ?

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951895/what-does-and-mean-in-scala

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a function literal

```
scala> val f = () => 1
f: () => Int = <function0>

scala> f()
res0: Int = 1
```

`map(_ => block)` would evaluate `block` immediately; by keeping it as a function we keep it lazy, which matters if we pass a `block` with side effects.

```
def foo2[T](block: => T) = List(1, 2, 3).map(_ => block)

scala> foo2(println("Hello"))
Hello
Hello
Hello
res1: List[Unit] = List((), (), ())

scala> foo(println("Hello"))
res2: List[() => Unit] = List(<function0>, <function0>, <function0>)

scala> res2.map(_())
Hello
Hello
Hello
res3: List[Unit] = List((), (), ())
```